# What does it mean by "Bottomless Persistent Storage"?

Tags: cloud, storage, distributed, persistent-storage

Need to understand what is "Bottomless" Persistent Storage in distributed systems

Comment: Yes, could not find relevant references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It essentially means no limit to the amount of data that can be stored. It would generally refer to the ability to scale a distributed system's persistence layer (generally databases) i.e. add more servers to the cloud indefinitely.